# Options pattern, configuration, in Legacy .NET Application with Simple Injector

Tags: configuration, simple-injector, configurationmanager, legacy-code, .net-core-configuration

This article, https://medium.com/@dmitryzaets/legacy-net-applications-configuration-management-net-framework-4-5-1-68220335d9d8, describe how to use Options pattern together with Autofac. I have tried to translate this to use with Simple Injector. But I have no luck.
Here is my IOC code

```cs
public class IocBootstrap2
{
    private Container Container { get; }
    public IocBootstrap2()
    {
        Container = new Container();
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Configuration"))
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        //Register Options
        Container.Register(typeof(IOptions<>), typeof(OptionsManager<>));
        Container.Register(typeof(IOptionsMonitor<>), typeof(OptionsMonitor<>));
        Container.Register(typeof(IOptionsFactory<>), typeof(OptionsFactory<>));
        Container.Register(typeof(IOptionsMonitorCache<>), typeof(OptionsCache<>));
        // Register ConfigurationOptions
        Container.RegisterConfigurationOptions2<MailingOptions>(configuration.GetSection("mailing"));

    #if DEBUG
        Container.Verify();
    #endif   
 }
}

public static class ConfigurationSetupExtensions2
{
    public static void RegisterConfigurationOptions2<TOptions>(this Container container, IConfiguration config)
        where TOptions : class
    {
        container.Register(typeof(IOptionsChangeTokenSource<TOptions>),
            () => new ConfigurationChangeTokenSource<TOptions>(config), Lifestyle.Transient);
        container.Register(typeof(IConfigureOptions<TOptions>),
            () => new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<TOptions>(config), Lifestyle.Transient);
    }
}
 public class MailingOptions
{
    public MailingOptions()
    {
        BatchSize = 1;
    }
    public int BatchSize { get; set; }
    public int BatchDelay { get; set; }
}
```

settings.json

```
{
  "mailing": {
    "batchSize": 15, 
    "batchDelay": 1
  }
}
```

Then I inject it in a ViewModel:s constructor like this

```cs
  public class BlockViewModel 
    {
        private readonly MailingOptions _options;

        #region Constructor
        public BlockViewModel(IOptions<MailingOptions> options) 
        {
            _options = options.Value;
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

When I run it I get Exceptions in Container.Verify.

> The constructor of type OptionsFactory<MailingOptions> contains the parameter with name 'setups' and type IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<MailingOptions>> that is not registered. Please ensure IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<MailingOptions>> is registered, or change the constructor of OptionsFactory<MailingOptions>. There is, however, a registration for IConfigureOptions<MailingOptions>; Did you mean to depend on IConfigureOptions<MailingOptions>?

StackTrace:

at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowParameterTypeMustBeRegistered(InjectionTargetInfo target)

How will I Register an `IEnumerable<IConfigureOptions<MailingOptions>>`?
Can someone tell my what I'm doing wrong, or more precise, what is it that I don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: don't inject `IOptions<T>` into your application components. As explained [here](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#working-with-ioptions-t), that will only complicate your components, their unit tests, and, as you already noticed, your configuration.

Instead, let `BlockViewModel` depend on `MailingOptions` directly:

```cs
public class BlockViewModel 
{
    private readonly MailingOptions _options;

    public BlockViewModel(MailingOptions options) 
    {
        _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }
}
```

This allows you to simplify your configuration to the following:

```cs
Container = new Container();
var configutation = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .SetBasePath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Configuration"))
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: false);
    .Build();

MailingOptions options = configuration.GetSection("mailing").Get<MailingOptions>();
Container.RegisterInstance<MailingOptions>(options);

// Register View Models
Container.Register<BlockViewModel>();

Container.Verify();
```

Comment: One thing to note on this answer: When you register the MailingOptions, it will be registered as a singleton. So its value will not be changed until the registration is explicitly updated (usually by restarting the app). A way around this is to do something like `RegisterFactory(() => configuration.GetSection("mailing").Get<MailingOptions>());` - If you do that, the config will get re-retrieved every time. Usually that's not necessary (and its slower). But if you want to be able to update your config on the fly without restarting the app, it's something to consider.

Comment: @JED, for that specific scenario where updates without restart are important, the `IOptionSnapshot<T>` model is more suited.